# Как создать функционал уведомлений о предстоящем мероприятии по наступлению даты события?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Всем доброго времени суток.

У меня есть два задания:

- Реализовать REST API для взаимодействия с мероприятиями/событиями
  (добавление/изменение/удаление + выборка событий по критериям).
- Реализовать функционал уведомлений о предстоящем мероприятии по наступлению
  даты события.

Первое задание реализовано,а вот со вторым что-то не складывается...
Пишу на Java с применением Spring+Spring Boot.
Если кто-то знает как это можно реализовать - буду очень благодарен.
Благодарю  Anton Sorokin,помог решить задание.
Еще плюс добавил логгирование,которое сохраняет событие в лог-файл.
Исходник кода - https://github.com/juk9210/events.

Comment: Подписка на события по e-mail? должен быть эндпоинт для регистрации подписчиков, табличка в базе. Можно включить планировщик, который раз в день (или несколько) запускается, шерстит базу на наличие событий на этот день, делает рассылку всем кто подписался

Comment: Нет,подписки как таковой нет и регистрации подписчиков тоже. Просто должно быть уведомление о событии.

Comment: @ЖеняШахов уведомление где и каким образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет аннотация [`@Sheduled`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks).  Для ее использование нужно поставить на Boot-класс аннотацию `@EnableSheduling`.

Вот пример метода:

```
//аннотация принимает cron, настроенный на каждый день
@Sheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
public void timerReminder() {
  //получаем текующую дату
  LocalDate nowDate = LocalDate.now();

  //делаем выборку событий в 'List<Event> events' по текующей дате 

  //каким-то образом рассылаем уведомления о событиях. Я просто вывожу их в консоль
  events.foreach(System.out::println);
}
```

Если вам надо послать их с помощью http-запроса, вы можете использовать [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

Для теста можно указать в аннотации `@Sheduled` `fixedRate = 1`, таким образом метод будет запускаться каждую секунду.

Comment: Интересное предложение,мне нравится. Что значит Boot-класс ?Типа класса Service или Apllication?

Comment: Нет, это класс с `main`-методом, где стоит аннотация `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Ну я и имел под словом Apllication класс  с main-методом

Comment: @ЖеняШахов ну что, у вас получилось? Я немного дополнил ответ

Comment: Еще не пробовал,да видел.Как сделаю отпишусь.

Comment: Да всё работает.Чуть дополнил  - сделал чтобы логгировало в лог-файл.
Очень благодарен.
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
    public void remindEvent() {
        LocalDate nowDate = LocalDate.now();
        List<Event> events = eventRepository.findEventsByDate( nowDate );
        for (Event event : events) {
            log.info( "Event have come : " + event.toString() );
        }
    }